# Unable to declare array of annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, metaprogramming, swagger

I have annotations on two methods

```
public class Question {

    @AnnotationA(value = { @AnnotationB(message = "One"), @AnnotationB(message = "Two") })
    public int methodOne() {
        return 1;
    }

    @AnnotationA(value = { @AnnotationB(message = "One"), @AnnotationB(message = "Two") })
    public int methodTwo() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and I would like to be able to write

```
public class Question {

    @AnnotationA(value = annoArray)
    public int methodOne() {
        return 1;
    }

    @AnnotationA(value = annoArray)
    public int methodTwo() {
        return 2;
    }

    public AnnotationB[] annoArray = { @AnnotationB(message = "One"), @AnnotationB(message = "Two") }
}
```

but I am informed by IntelliJ that `Annotations are not allowed here` at the location of the `annoArray`.

Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because annotations must be compile time constants. However you have at least two possibilities:

1. You can create constants for the AnnoationB values.
2. If AnnotationB only holds a String and you need multiple you can define AnnotationA's value member to be a String[] (also you could define Constants here)